# Only one line in TypeScript file, I get: cannot redeclare block-scoped variable WHEN i compile

Tags: typescript

I am writing only one line of code in my ex1.ts in my Visual Studio Code:

```
let n: number = 10;
```

When I do compile, using:

```
tsc ex1.ts
```

the compiler generate the ex1.js file correctly but immediately VSC prints out an error in the .ts file:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'n'.ts(2451)
ty1.js(1, 5): 'n' was also declared here.
```

So basically VSC tells me that there's another let n variable... but it's in the .js file, not in the .ts file.
My understanding of TypeScript is that it's a tool for compiling .js file with strict typechecking. Why does it make conflict with unrelated .js and .ts file?

The error disappears immediately when I delete the .js file. The files are located in a simple "exercises" folder.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a .js and .ts file in the same directory with the same (base) filename? Why?

Comment: when you compile, you get a .js version of your .ts file... with the same name of course

Comment: Normally that's in a different directory though. Can you share the .js output?

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on your typescript code, you should have the .js file closed, that's it.

I hope you already fix this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29797198)